# Latin "niger" from *negʷ-?

Tags: etymology, historical-linguistics, proto-indo-european, latin, comparative-linguistics

Could Latin *niger* "black", of uncertain origin, come from *negʷ- "bare, naked"?

For an analogy, compare *black*, *blank*, Spanish *blanco* "white, argent", and their roots PGem *blakaz "burnt", PGem *blankaz "white, bright, blinding", PIE *bʰleg- and *bʰleyǵ- respectively, both “to shine”. *bleak* in OE could mean "shiny", from PGem *blaikaz "pale, white", also from PIE *bʰleyǵ-. All taken from wiktionary, none sourced but often taken from LIV or Pokorny.

At least *bleak* and *niger* both have negative connotations.

Ger. *Blanker* is short for *blanker Hintern* "naked butt"; *blankes Kabel* is an exposed, unisolated wire, perhaps not dull (oxidized) so as to be conductive.

Supposing there was the slur *nig- or *neg- "slave, dark skin" (cp. *nigger*, *negro*, *Neger*) or something close, which should be hard to falsify, the idea is it would have been formative for *niger*, because one common justification for enslavement, not just "Negroes", was incivility, and that would stereotypically include nakedness. Also, slaves would have to appear naked at auctions and often cater to sexual submission.

For comparison *maurus* "Moor, Mauritanian, African" is comparable to Ancient Greek μαυρός (mauros) "dark, black, dim, weak, ...", which is uncertain but might derive from the name of the Moors. (Edit: notes of unyielding comparisons removed)

I'm afraid I'm too pessimistic, and downright paranoid about not being pessimistic enough about the darker parts of history. So, any input would be appreciated, in comments. Although, an answer should focus on publications on the matter.

Edit:

Following *maurus*, I wonder, can a comparison *Nubian* versus *nudus* "nude" be fruitful? *nudus* is derived from PIE *nogʷedós through *gʷ > Lt. *u* (thanks @TKR), but *b* < *du* is not unknown in Latin (cp. *bellum*, *duellum*). The etymology of *Nubia* is unclear to me, not Egyptian apparently, unless from *nwb* "gold".

A term encountered in Roman ideas about slavery is *social death*. Hence including *necro* in the comparison might be helpful. The negation marker *ne should be considerable. Insofar the actually used word was *mortis, mors*, cp. *maurus*.

Comment: Slurs like "n-gger" postdate Classical Latin by millennia. The Romans kept slaves from all across the world, regardless of skin color; Gauls from France were seen as less civilized than e.g. Carthaginians from Northern Africa.

Comment: @Draconis "*Slurls like*" are you saying *Classical Latin* didn't have slurls? Sure, it's cleaned up. *Vulgar Latin* is a different matter. That's my point. That makes it hard to date without doubt. "*regardless of skin color*"--again, my point precisely. Although, my focus on slavery might be distracting. Words gaining an opposite meaning, is not unprecedented anyhow.

Comment: From a [relevant Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_people_in_Ancient_Roman_history): "While slavery was a deeply-stigmatized social status, the great majority of slaves were from European and Mediterranean populations; inherited physical characteristics were not relevant to slave status. Black people were not excluded from any profession, and there was usually no stigma or bias against mixed race relationships in Antiquity."

Comment: @LjL [Αἰθίοψ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Αἰθίοψ) "... αἴθω (aíthō, “I burn”) +‎ ὤψ (ṓps, “face”) ... likely a folk etymology ... the first assumed root always has senses related to brightness and never to darkness ..." Then compare ὤψ "eye, face; word" PIE *h₃ekʷ-* "to see, eye" and Latin *ops* "power to help; recources, wealth, PIE *h₃ep-* "to work, toil; force, ability" and remember that *kʷ-* can become "p" eventually; cp. "see to it". Is is possible that noble (light faced?) clothed Ethiopians are not comparable? cp. *barbar*~*Berber*; Aesop as slave.

Comment: [cont] Contrast that with ὄψ "word" *wekʷ-*. "to sound out"; cp. *weǵ-* "lively, awake; strong" (viz. *h₃ep-* "force"); cp. ἔθω, *ethos*, from *swe-dʰh₁-* "self+do" (?), *sound* "healthy", from *sunt~*swent-, *sound* "noise", from *swen- "to resound". At this point we are not talking about Classical Latin anymore. While the development to *swésōr* "sister" is not known, considering possible derivations for "aphrodite", I'd suppose that some Africans were seen as *Black brothers and sisters*. Those how ever weren't shy of taking slaves, either. Also compare Nubian with Egy. *nebu* "gold".

Comment: Is there any evidence that there existed a 'slur *niger* "slave, dark skin"', or that 'one common justification for enslavement ... was incivility'? Also I don't understand the point of your last two comments, which list a bunch of PIE roots that are unrelated to each other and to the topic of the question.

Comment: @TKR Tabooization makes your first part moot. It's an interesting question, but you are missing the point: "naked" can be directed at anyone. The association with *n!ggers* is biased surely, but it's not impossible. The times when *niger* is already fairly established, surely very early, are not a priority for the question. By LjL's comment, our current society is in no part racist, just because we had Barack Obama as figurehead for a few years, and people don't dare write "nigger" in polite society; But we couldn't have a Clarence Thomas just 300 years ago. Think in Wave-Models, not linearly.

Comment: So there's no evidence... Anyway I'm not convinced Latin even had "taboo" words. Lots of extremely rude words are attested in Latin literature.

Comment: [cont] At least, now I know where I'm missing background. One point I just read is that black people were regarded as "exotic". Could there have been a fad producing youth slang, that sticks and doesn't have such a severe connotation? Overall I just don't see convincing evidence, but I want to keep thinking about it. So, to your second point, analogies might help. Those are not all unrelated. *black* for one is clearly related, semantically, to *noir*. bʰleg- and *bʰleyǵ- “to shine” look similar enough to suspect interrelation. Whether none of the "m-" words are related, is a different matter.

Comment: You might like to ask this at the [Latin.se] site.

Comment: @vectory There absolutely were slurs, obscene words, etc in Latin, but *niger* wasn't one of them. It's attested as a name, probably meaning something like "dark-haired", and I believe (though I'd have to double-check and find a source) that the standard word for people with dark skin was instead *caeruleus*. (If you're interested in the Latin word and its usage, you could probably get much better answers on Latin.SE which Dannii linked above!)

Comment: I wasn't sure how to phrase that part. I changed it to an asterix-marked notation to show that it's unattested.

Comment: Also, it wasn't quite *d>b in Latin, it was *dw>b. *Necros* was a Greek word for "corpse", not Latin at all, and *maurus* was afaik a loan from Greek—while the Romans would have known both words, those borrowings postdate the word *niger* by quite a long time.

Comment: *maurus* is interesting for analogy; its root is uncertain; geographically, Latin is closer to Iberia, but it's not said who gave the name. *necros* corresponds to Lt. *noxa, nex*, and is interesting for the root PIE *neḱ-* (also, cp. *zombi*). The "du" in *nudus* is not read "dw", but cp. *bis<duis, duo*; "in word-initial position" could work if "nu-" was from *ne* "not" understood as prefix. PIE *mer-* goes to *mors* "death", *mare* "sea" and En. *mere* "pure, only"--the sea-people, on horseback? cp. OArm *merk* "nude", from PIE *n-egw*, cp. *new*, uncertain (*new*, *fresh*, *nude*? *now*?).

Comment: @vectory: For some mysterious reason, you seem, to think that the Latin words *negro* and *niger* are mainly or primarily related to *people*. They aren't. (Were that the case, they'd probably be nouns, rather than adjectives, which is what they are). Neither in Latin itself, nor in any modern languages descendant from it, including my own, do these words refer to nakedness, nor are they *primarily* used to describe living beings (e.g., black dogs, black humans, black ravens, etc). Rather, they are now, and have always been, used to describe blackness *of any kind* (e.g., the night, darkness).

Comment: @Lucian it's a proposition that's not disqualified by your blank assertions. You didn't understand the analogy either. The word might relate to people for mysterious reasons, indeed. In fact, *mysterious* is one common connotation of the word. It's surely used in noun like propensity, e.g. in "*Nigrum in candida vertere*" or "*nigros efferre maritos*", although that's saying nothing about how it had been used in pre-recorded times.

Comment: @vectory: Which *blank assertions* might those be ? The *fact* that both within surviving Latin writings, as well as all extant Romance languages descended from it, including my own, the word never carries any other connotation than *blackness* ? The only language using *negro* to refer strictly to human beings is English, which does *not* descend from Latin, and whose use of the word does *not* date back to [Roman times](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_Britain). In all Romance languages, including my own, turning adjectives into nouns is quite common, but they are not primarily nouns.

Comment: @Lucian You made claims about the word that can be falsified with a Latin dictionary. More over, your "*have always been*" is unfounded. My supposition of n-words in Latin seems to irk you the wrong way. Let me disclaim, I'm far from racists and I know my biases. A comparison of all descendent cultures implies that institutional racism and other kinds of discrimination were the norm, earlier, much earlier, which is more important for the question than whether Latin had an n-word for slaves, black or not. I just don't know how to adjust the question appropriately, but I will try.

Comment: @vectory: In case my previous comments weren't clear enough, the only people from the face of the planet who think that *negro* is either a racist slur, or distinctly linked to humans, are usually native English speakers. Your insistence on *negro* originally meaning *naked* (which is completely unattested), and then becoming *black* when Latins met Africans (as opposed to when Latins encountered darkness for the first time) is as absurd as saying the English word *green* appeared only when Americans (thought they) met Martians (as opposed to, say, when they first encountered vegetation).

Comment: @Lucian a possible construction like *niger skin* (*cutis niger*) makes your remark irrelevant. As I'm told Romans did not, to the best of present knowledge, mass import subsaharan African slaves, I have to revise the idea. The important bit is *naked*. How that cold turn *dark, black* is the question. The answer that it always had meant black is unfounded, so I merely insist there might be more to it. The word *green* appeared relatively late, indeed. Before that, yellow and green were lumped together, derived from a sense *gleaming, shiny*, like many color words did, I suppose.

Comment: @vectory: Why on earth would the (obvious) existence of expressions like *black skin* or *naked skin* (in Latin or other languages) render my remark(s) irrelevant ? What happened to the original Latin word for *black*, once they've supposedly changed it with the former word for *naked* ? Were North Africans particularly naked in the first place ? (I'm asking this because I have in my possession a five volume *History of Fashion* book, whose first tome contains over thirty pages dedicated solely to Ancient Egyptian clothing).

Comment: @Lucian a) The premises is that the construction did very transparently not mean "black skin" in the meaning, became opaque and shifted meaning, in Latin or earlier. b) Latin has at least three synonyms for black, and probably more for dark. c) I specifically didn't indicate North Africans, however I'm not sure that makes much of a difference if North Africa had a sprawling slave industry. Aesop is said to be Ethiopian d) hunter gatherers remain naked to this day around the world. e) Ancient people are frequently pictured with just loincloth or the like, as naked as Adam and Eve in my book.

Comment: Not to forget Aphrodite, and ancient fascination with dark skin, so it's not all negative, to be sure. I'm reluctant to consider Slavs instead, because it stays with the slave theme for one, and is difficult for several other reasons. Anyhow, instead of a direct transition from "naked" to "black", a sense of "dirty" inbetween might be considerable. cp *nick* "blemish", akin to Ger *Knick* "kink", from PGem \*hnīganą, \*hnīwaną, from PIE *\*kneygʷʰ-* "to bend, bow", from \*ken- "to press, pinch, kink". To get \*negʷ- from that, think "unravel, develop, unfold", Ger *wickeln, windeln*. *ey>Lt i?

Comment: @vectory: Ethiopians are not particularly naked either, and, regardless, Latins are not Africans (at least then your hypothesis would be somewhat plausible). Here's my theory: You are a native English speaker, and all your theories are explained by *the distinctly English usage of negro to refer to black humans specifically, as opposed to all things black in general, as is the norm in all languages actually descending from Latin*, which is why you keep beating up the same dead horse over and over again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Semantically it seems easier to start from PIE *negʷ- "dark" (the source of the word for "night" in many languages), though of course it's possible that this and the "naked" root are actually the same -- a semantic link doesn't seem impossible. Such an etymology for *niger* has in fact been suggested by Frisk, specifically from *negʷ-ró- (with the common adjectival suffix *-ró-); cf. Arm. *nerk* "color". The only formal difficulty with this etymology is the vowel change: though there are sporadic cases of *e > *i* in Latin, it doesn't seem to have been a regular change. (As for *gʷ, though it regularly gives Latin *u*, there is an exception before *r*, so that *gʷr > *gr*.) Though this is a problem, it isn't a huge one and I'm surprised that de Vaan, the most recent etymological dictionary of Latin, doesn't even mention this idea.

Comment: Well *gʷr does give gr word initally at least (eg. gravis), not sure if word medially. But yeah *e > i is inexplicable here, and wouldn't one expect the zero grade with -ró- anyway?

Comment: @user54748 Word-medially too, cf. *mīgrō : ἀμείβω from *h₂meigʷ(-r-). You're right that -ró- generally takes zero grade but there do seem to be some e-grades, e.g. *cārus* < *keh₂-ró-; and Arm. *nerk* < *negʷ-ró- seems to be an accepted etymology.

Comment: Does De Vaan offer a different etymology? I'm afraid I don't have easy access to his work.

Comment: @Draconis No, he just says "Unknown etymology".